# django template turn array into HTML table

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list of 16 results, let's call it "results". I want to arrange them in a 4 x 4 table.

Using the django template, how can I do this? (It doesn't seem like cycle would help me here)

```
<table>
{% for r in results %}
...?
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the `cycle` tag for this.

```
<table>
  {% for r in results %}
    {% cycle '<tr>' '' '' '' %}
      <td>{{r.content}}</td>
    {% cycle '' '' '' '</tr>' %}
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Would output something like...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>result 1</td>
    <td>result 2</td>
    <td>result 3</td>
    <td>result 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>result 5</td>
    <td>result 6</td>
    <td>result 7</td>
    <td>result 8</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- etc -->
</table>
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to build something like this

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>header1</th>
  <th>header2</th>
  <th>header3</th>
  <th>header4</th>
</tr>
{% for r in result %}
<tr>
  <th> {{ result.name }}</th>
  <th> {{ result.address }}</th>
  <th> {{ result.time }}</th>
  <th> {{ result.date }}</th>
</tr> 
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

provided that you have an array (actually, a dictionary) this way

```
result['name']
result['address']
result['time']
result['date']
return render_to_response("my_template.html", {'result:result'})
```

There are a number of do this. This is the most straightforward ways. Look at Django template tag documentation.

Here is a list of techniques I learned throughout. There are more, but I don't have time to document all of them.
http://binarybugs01.appspot.com/entry/template-iteration-techniques

Sometimes you have to be careful with the context dictionary you are passing to the template.
If you are passing this

```
result = {'name': 'John', 'time': '12/2/2012'....etc}
context['result'] = result
return render_to_response("my_template.html", context}
```

You are iterating over `result.result` and the keys are `result.result.name`

---

I also want to remind you that you either have a list, a set, a dictionary, or a tuple.You can import array and use it, however.

Comment: not result.name i think its r.name and r.time, r.address,r.date
       {% for r in result %}
           <tr>
               <th> {{ result.name }}</th>
              <th> {{ result.address }}</th>
              <th> {{ result.time }}</th>
             <th> {{ result.date }}</th>
           </tr> 
        {% endfor %}

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have:
`results=[[1, 2, 3, 4,], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]`

The following template can be used to display results in a table:

```
<table>
  {% for rowval in results %}    
     <tr>
     {% for val in rowval %}
      <td>{{val}}</td>
     {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

It will display:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```