# Django HTML template table rendering

Tags: django

I want to render a table look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some data</td>
    <th>special one</th>
    <td>some data</td>
      ...
    <td>some data</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59720787/8138241) that can render all in the same tag.

```
<table>
  {% for rowval in results %}    
     <tr>
     {% for val in rowval %}
      <td>{{val}}</td>
     {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

But in my case, there would be a **`th`** at the second place for every row of the data, if there is a record.

There is another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016316/sending-html-to-django-template-from-view) that not as good as the answer below as it keeps partial table, `td` and `tr` in the view.

Is there a way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some variables available inside a django template [for loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for), one of them is named `forloop.counter` which gives you the current iteration of the loop. You can use this variable to render something differently on the second loop

```
<table>
  {% for rowval in results %}    
    <tr>
      {% for val in rowval %}
        {% if forloop.counter == 2 %}
          <th>{{ val }}</th>
        {% else %}
          <td>{{ val }}</td>
        {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: That's brilliant!! I didn't know there is a forloop counter available.